# Postgres - want a database to have two names

Tags: postgresql, alias, synonyms

One of my Postgres databases is named entirely in upper-case, and a new bit of software needs to see it in lower-case. I've tried renaming it, but unfortunately that breaks the huge multitude of things that already rely on it being in upper-case (as they've got quotes in the connection string so need it in upper case). Going through and fixing those would be a risky, mammoth undertaking as there is nobody in the company left who originally created the database and all the things that rely on it, and documentation is scarce.

As such, I've come to the conclusion that the best way forwards is to leave the existing database as it is, but to try and have it available by two names - its original name, and a new name. I would imagine just about everyone here already knows of something like this anyway, but I'm relatively new. I've seen terms like alias and synonym in my Googling.

However, I don't believe either of these can be done to an entire database (if I'm wrong then I would be very happy with some information to go on). I've also tried creating an empty database (with the nice new lower-case name) and creating simple views to the original's tables, but of course views don't generally go cross-database.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT - also quickly tried dblink, which looks like it could do the job. Its an unknown function, so I'm guessing the version of postgres we're running is old. May see if we can upgrade it.

Comment: You could use [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html) instead of views. This is the preferred way nowadays over the dblink module

Comment: I wonder if you could use a connection through [service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) for the new software

Comment: The directory name in the `base` directory in the data directory is the same as the OID of the entry in the `pg_database` table. If you create a symlink there … it will probably blow up horribly, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: The database name is used in a single place in the network protocol (in the StartupMessage); it would be possible to modify and recompile Postgres or libpq to modify this value appropriately.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name will a service file work with JDBC connections, too?

Comment: @dezso: no, it doesn't look like JDBC supports that (but typically JDBC connections configured through DataSources which is rarely handled in a way where the database name can't be changed, so I assumed it's not a Java/JDBC program)

Comment: _new bit of software needs to see it in lower-case_: it looks like a case of misunderstanding case folding rules, either from you or from the author of that software. The root cause should be fixed, because the workarounds you're looking at are extreme compared to the simplicity of the bug.

Comment: @DanielVérité Agreed! Unfortunately the manufacturer of the software is a large company who appears more than a bit stubborn. They've categorically told us that the database needs to be in lower-case.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone, sounds pretty hopeful. As mentioned, the software vendor has basically said it needs to be in lower-case and are unwilling to do anything about it. We're currently using postgres 9.1 which is a bit too low for any of the answers, but we are looking at upgrading. I'll see if I can get the guys responsible to speed up a bit.